# The use of has or have to answer question

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct out of the sentences below?

> **Has** your children been to the US ?

or

> **Have** your children been to the US?

Comment: Please let me reframe it appropriately. Has your children been to the US? or Have your children been to the US?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Timinycricket's answer, please note that your concern is about subject-verb agreement.

"[Has](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-have.html)" is the singular form of the verb, while "have" is the plural.

Considering that **[children](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=children%20definition&oq=children%20definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.3175j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)** is a plural noun, you should use "have", not "has".

Answer (score 0):

If it is singular then it would be:

> Has your child been to the US?

If more than one it would be:

> Have your children been to the US?